# How to change the library include path of a binary from bash?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, include-path, kde4

I have a software properly installed on Kubuntu.

Now, I am patching and testing some of its libraries.

How can I start the software from bash so that it loads my patched libraries instead of the official libs?

e.g.:
the official libs are locate in /usr/lib/
my patch libraries (used during test development) are in /home/user/dev/lib/

I tried:

```
$ set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/dev/lib/  
$ binary_app &
```

but to no avail.

I'd prefer a solution that can be set from the bash, but if it's not possible, I could also modify the cmake file of this C++ software.

The aim is to allow me to easily start the application either with the vanilla libs, or with my patched libs to see the differences.

**Edit: it's a KDE .so file**

The library I am testing is a KDE4 library. The official lib is in /usr/lib/kde4/ . In that directory, none of the library start with the **lib** prefix.

Whether I do:

```
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --list  --library-path PATH EXEC
```

or

```
ldd EXEC
```

The library is not listed at all.

On the other hand, if if move the original library away from /usr/lib/kde4/, the application starts but the corresponding functionality is missing.

Are KDE4 libraries loaded in a specific way? Maybe the variable to set is different...

**Edit 2**

All the answers are good and useful... unfortunately, it turned out that the problem does not appear to be related to the lib path setting. I'm dealing with a plugin architecture and the .so loading path appears to be hard-coded somewhere in the application. I need to spend more time within the source code to understand what's happening... Thanks and +1 to all.

Comment: You can check with `ldd binary_app` which libraries it uses. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should work but maybe a similar named library is in the ld cache which prevents `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from beeing used. Or you can try ldpreload: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230

Comment: Yes, check whether it shall pick up you library in the absence of the real one? This try will shed some light on your situation.

Comment: I tried both suggestions. preload didn't work because I'm dealing with a KDE/QT app: error: QPixmap: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From 'man bash':

> When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to
>   be executed, it is invoked in a
>   separate execution environment that
>   consists of the following.  Unless
>   otherwise noted, the values are
>   inherited from the shell.
>
> [....]
>
> · shell variables and functions marked for export, along
>        with variables exported for the
>   command, passed in the environment

You need to 'export' a variable if it is to be seen by programs you execute.

However, you can also try the following:

> /lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path PATH EXECUTABLE

See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: Thanks. In my case, it's actually /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 . It still doesn't work, probably because I'm dealing with a KDE4 shared object. See edit to the question.

Comment: Even though it was rve who pointed out the source of my actual problem (hard-coded .so loading procedure/path), I accept this answer because it might me the most useful to someone reading this question with a similar problems. The other answers were all useful as well. +1 to all.

Answer (score 5):

Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` instead of set.

Comment: In either case echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH outputs the proper path. Using export does not seem to make any difference... :(

Comment: @augustin - you won't see the difference from the shell. But processes started from the shell inherit only exported variables.

Answer (score 3):

I already put this in a comment but after thinking about it I think the best way to do this (using a different library just for testing/debugging) is using `LD_PRELOAD`, see [What is the LD_PRELOAD trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230)

From the man page:

> **LD_PRELOAD**
>
> A whitespace-separated list of additional, user-specified, ELF shared libraries to be loaded before all others. This can be used to selectively override functions in other shared libraries. For set-user-ID/set-group-ID ELF binaries, only libraries in the standard search directories that are also set-user-ID will be loaded.

Update:

After the updated question it seems the application is using `dlopen` to open the library using a absolute path. I don't think you can do anything about it. See `man dlopen`

Update2:

Maybe there is something you can do: you might be able to `LD_PRELOAD` your own `dlopen` function which modifies the path to your own library...

Comment: it seem you are right: I need to spend more time in this app's source code to understand how the .so are loaded. See edit 2. I grepped for dlopen but got zero result. I need to investigate more and/or contact the actual application developer to see how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't you app setuid or setgid by chance? In this case LD_LIBRARY_PATH will be ignored.

Comment: Good thinking, but no, there is no setuid.

Answer (score 2):

Put everything on one line:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo binary_app&
```